# bang seems to not exclude files in .gitignore

Tags: git

I have a `foo` directory which contains 2 files, `bar` and `baz`. I have the following `.gitignore` file, right above the `foo` directory:

```
foo/
!foo/baz
```

I expect this to ignore everything in the `foo` directory except it should **not** ignore `baz`.

However, everything in `foo` is still being ignored. If I run `git check-ignore foo/*`, I get:

```
foo/bar
foo/baz
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `foo/*` and then `!foo/baz` ?

Comment: I just tried that, and it made no difference.

Comment: Never mind... it's working now... I had to do `git add foo` first.

Comment: However, as mentioned below, there seems to be a bug in `check-ignore`... even if I correct `.gitignore` to specify the *, `check-ignore` only gives correct output after I do: `git add foo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That particular formulation is not supported in [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

> An optional prefix "`!`" which negates the pattern; any matching file
>   excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. It is not
>   possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is
>   excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance
>   reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter
>   where they are defined. Put a backslash ("`\`") in front of the first
>   "`!`" for patterns that begin with a literal "`!`", for example,
>   "`\!important!.txt`".

Instead, you can do:

```
foo/*
!foo/baz
```

Here's an example session so that you can see it in action:

```
:: tree
.
`-- foo/
    |-- bar
    `-- baz

:: cat .gitignore
foo/*
!foo/baz

:: git status -sb
## Initial commit on master
?? .gitignore
?? foo/

:: git add foo
:: git status -sb
## Initial commit on master
A  foo/baz
?? .gitignore
```

Note that baz was added but bar was ignored.

To see what things look like if baz was not in foo, we can reset and then remove baz:

```
:: git reset
:: rm foo/baz
:: git status -sb
## Initial commit on master
?? .gitignore
```

Note that foo doesn't show up here, even though foo/bar still exists.

Comment: I just tried that and it made no difference... same output from `check-ignore`

Comment: Never mind... it's working now... I had to do `git add foo` first.

Comment: Yeah, the status output is a bit weird.  It'll show you that foo is unversioned until a file underneath it has been added.  However, if all you had in there was just bar, then it would not show up in the status at all.  Actually, I update this to show that.

Comment: Also, if you don't do the `add`, then `check-ignore` says that it will ignore everything

Comment: That could be a bug in check-ignore. :-(

Comment: I realized I had a global gitignore `~/.gitignore_global` that was driving me nuts wondering why this pattern didn't seem to work 